# How do I create a strong enough password without making it difficult to remember?

Tags: passwords

I'm not a fan of complex passwords as I have a hard time remembering them. Because of that I like the message of this [comic](http://www.explainxkcd.com/2011/08/10/password-strength/).

However typing the sentence "*correct horse battery staple*" into this [calculator](https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm) yields "*12.41 trillion trillion trillion centuries*" as opposed to the comic's "*550 years*".

How can they differ so much, which one is correct if any and how would I know?
How do I create a strong enough password without making it difficult to remember?

Comment: Does it matter if it is 550 years opposed to 12.41 trillion trillion trillion centuries? :P

Comment: That calculator looks like a great way to harvest passwords.  All it needs is an email sign-up form :)  In all seriousness, they're probably both correct.  There's a lot more to it than just "X amount of complexity = Y amount of time."  They're using different formulas, making different assumptions, etc.  It's highly likely that within a few years both of their assumptions will be incorrect and the values would change.

Comment: It matters since we have Moore's law and scenarios with much more than 1000 guesses per second to account for.

Comment: The comic says the password entropy of the phrase is 2^44 while the calculator says it's 3.90 x 10^49. I'm guessing the calculator is right, but am very curious about how the comic arrives at 2^44.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this difference is basically given on the linked side itself:

> IMPORTANT!!!    What this calculator is NOT . . .
>
> It is NOT a “Password Strength Meter.”
>
> Since it could be easily confused for one, it is very important for you to understand what it is, and what it isn't:
>
> The #1 most commonly used password is “123456”, and the 4th most common is “Password.” So any password attacker and cracker would try those two passwords immediately. Yet the Search Space Calculator above shows the time to search for those two passwords online (assuming a very fast online rate of 1,000 guesses per second) as 18.52 minutes and 17.33 centuries respectively! If “123456” is the first password that's guessed, that wouldn't take 18.52 minutes. And no password cracker would wait 17.33 centuries before checking to see whether “Password” is the magic phrase.

The caclulator basically only considers [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) attempts, while an actual attack would probably be a [dictionary arrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack). Since most combinations of letters are not actual words a dictionary attack will try a lot less combinations, thous getting a result much faster

Comment: 17.33 centuries to crack "Password"... awesome.

Comment: The comic doesn't take password stats into account. It says it takes  2^44 guesses for the given phrase. It would take its time to crack "Password" too.

Answer (score 0):

> IMPORTANT!!!    What this calculator is NOT . . .
>
> It is NOT a “Password Strength Meter.”

The calculator assumes that cracker uses exhaustive search. xkcd assumes that cracker may know (or guess) your method of generating password and needs to check only the passwords which you can choose. xkcd method is far safer.

Answer (score 0):

Not any strong password is 100% safe, few websites can really protect user's password. You'd better not to use only one password everywhere. What you do is to keep the straw on fire away from others.

What I do is:

1. a unforgettable password: A;
2. the website asking for a password, "www.example.com", as B;
3. get C = md5(A) + md5(B), and use the leading 8 characters of C as the password;
4. write a simple script for this, and of course, you may adjust the algorithm, and do keep the script on cloud.

the browser will save password for us, if it asks you for re-enter the password, you can get it back at once.

The operator '+' is not as strcat. It means:
I get the md5 in low letters, and saying that the '0' values 0, ..., 'a' values 10, ..., 'A' is 36, ..., and as so on.Then calculate the result at every character with their values, discarding the carry, and do "mod(62)".